# do something when an ajax call is successful in axios - chaining then() in axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to do something when an ajax call is successful in axios

```
    save() {

      this.isUpdateTask ? this.updateProduct() : this.storeProduct()

      this.endTask()

    }
```

if the ajax call to update or store the product is successful, I want to run the endTask() function.

I don't want the endTask() function to be run when the ajax call is not successful.

how can I do that?

the store function:

```
    storeProduct() {
      return axios
        .post("products", this.getFormData())
        .then(
          response => this.products.push(response.data.data)
        )
        .catch(
          error => (this.serverErrors = error.response.data.errors.detail)
        )
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call this methods inside a new promise like this below example:

```
   save() {
      Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        return this.isUpdateTask ? this.updateProduct() : this.storeProduct()
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.endTask()
      })
    }
```

Have other ways to do also:

```
save() {
  (this.isUpdateTask ? this.updateProduct() : this.storeProduct()).then(() => {
    this.endTask()
  })
}
```

Or assign to a variable:

```
save() {
  const promiseUpdate = this.isUpdateTask ? this.updateProduct() : this.storeProduct()

  promiseUpdate.then(() => {
    this.endTask()
  })
}
```

Or with async/await:

```
async save() {
  await this.isUpdateTask ? this.updateProduct() : this.storeProduct()
  // this code runs only if everything happen successful
  await this.endTask()
}
```

---

And about the `endTask` execute until when response is not successful, is because you treat the `error` inside the storProduct.

```
.catch(
  error => (this.serverErrors = error.response.data.errors.detail)
)
```

So, in this case, is necessary re-throw the error again:

```
.catch(
  error => {
    this.serverErrors = error.response.data.errors.detail
    throw error
  }
)
```

The `catch` of Promise, have same effect of `try/catch` from javascript.

Have more reference about `catch` on promise [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#Using_and_chaining_the_catch_method).

Comment: You should be able to assign `this.isUpdateTask ? this.updateProduct() : this.storeProduct()` to a variable, so `Promise.resolve()` isn't necessary.

Comment: Good, I'm gonna add more examples :)

Comment: I tried the second way yesterday, but today I noticed that the endTask() runs even when the response is not successful and for example, there is a validation error.

Comment: the endTask() in promiseUpdate.then() is supposed to run when the response is successful. but it is run even when there is a validation error.

Comment: Good, now I got you, I added more exemplo about this on end post.

Comment: awesome!! I added the "throw error" and now everything works how it's supposed to. Thanks a lot Fuechter

Answer (score 1):

Anything inside the `.then` is only executed when a successful response is received

```
.then(response => {
    this.products.push(response.data.data)
    this.save()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
storeProduct() {
  return axios
    .post("products", this.getFormData())
    .then(
      response => this.products.push(response.data.data)
      this.endTask();  //call endtask() here after successfull api call and response back from api
    )
    .catch(
      error => (this.serverErrors = error.response.data.errors.detail)
    )
}
```

Comment: I did this at first, but I want the storeProduct() to have one single responsibility. I don't want it to be involved with ending the task.

Comment: Then set any boolean flag for the API success response. Means if API gives success response then set flag true. If flag true then call this.endTask() function. Make initially flag false.

Comment: yeah, this is what I'm doing temporarily. it is not the best way but it does the job. I wonder why then() function runs when there is validation error.